# If I have a connection in a using statement, will the connection be closed if an exception occurs in the using statement?

Tags: c#, database, exception, connection, using

The following code doesn't have any sort of error handling.

I'm curious though. As it sits, will the connection that is created in the using statement be closed when the exception is thrown? Or will the connection remain open because it was never explicitly closed?

```
public override string ResetToDefault() {
    string result;
    using (var cn = HostFacade.GetDbConnection())
    {
        cn.Open();
        DbProvider.Transaction = cn.BeginTransaction();

        // Do something here that throws an unhandled exception.

        DbProvider.Transaction.Commit();
        cn.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Edit: The connection being returned by HostFacade.GetDbConnection is an IDbConnection. It's safe here to assume it's being implemented as a SqlConnection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because a `using` statement is expanded by the compiler to be a `try...finally` block. Your code is the same as this:

```
SqlConnection cn = null;

try {
    cn = HostFacade.GetDbConnection();
    cn.Open();
    // .. rest of the code here
}
finally {
    if (cn != null)
        cn.Dispose();
}
```

The `Dispose` call will close the connection.

The CLR guarantees that a finally block will execute.. except in very specific scenarios (such as a call to `FailFast` IIRC).

Comment: _The Dispose call will close the connection._ are you sure about that?

Comment: @Selman22 Yes.. I am. From the documentation: `To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block`. Reflector also backs it up with a call to `this.Close()` in the `Dispose` method of `SqlConnection`.

Comment: And if no using statement were provided, would it then leave the connection open? In other words, does the compiler only expect to the try...finally block when a using statement is implemented?

Comment: Well it is not really closed if it is a pooled connection. If you look at the reference source you could see that the call to Close does nothing, and in the following DisposeMe there is a check on the Pooling option. However from the viewpoint of this question, the connection is closed.

Comment: Lets read the question as its meant to be written then: `Does this leak resources?`. Answer: no.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of `Dispose()` by the author of the specific library you are running.

Libraries built into the .NET Framework (like your example) will undoubtedly clean up the resources accessed, like the `SqlConnection`, but you should verify with documentation first, before assuming anything.